# How do I get the STX character of hex 02

Tags: c#, character-encoding, hex

I have a device to which I'm trying to connect via a socket, and according to the manual, I need the "STX character of hex 02".

How can I do this using C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a Unicode character escape: `\u0002`

Answer (score 15):

Just a comment to GeoffM's answer (I don't have enough points to comment the proper way).

You should never embed STX (or other characters) that way using only two digits.

If the next character (after "\x02") was a valid hex digit, that would also be parsed and it would be a mess.

```
string s1 = "\x02End";
string s2 = "\x02" + "End";
string s3 = "\x0002End";
```

Here, s1 equals ".nd", since 2E is the dot character, while s2 and s3 equal STX + "End".

Answer (score 2):

Cast the `Integer` value of 2 to a `char`:

```
char cChar = (char)2;
```

Answer (score 1):

`\x02` is STX Code you can check [the ASCII Table](https://ostermiller.org/calc/ascii.html)

```
checkFinal = checkFinal.Replace("\x02", "End").ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Within a string, clearly the [Unicode format is best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9585857/3063884), but for use as a byte, this approach works:

```
byte chrSTX = 0x02; // Start of Text
byte chrETX = 0x03; // End of Text
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the STX within a string like so:

```
byte[] myBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\x02Hello, world!");
socket.Send(myBytes);
```