# How to identify STX character in a string

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I am using TCPClient in my code, and I can find start and end of the text in a string successfully.

`e.g
Start of Text : <Root> 
End of Text : </Root>`

But I have another string which contains `STX` at the beginning of the string. How can I identify `STX` in c#?

Comment: Isn't String.StartsWith or String.Contains enough?

Comment: Have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585828/how-do-i-get-the-stx-character-of-hex-02

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I think its special character.

Comment: `char STX = (char) 3;` ... `if (source.StartsWith(STX))`...

Comment: @DmitryBychenko : if source is string, then StartsWith will except string and not character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`STX` is just a [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character

```
const char STX = '\u0002';
```

And you can work with it like with any other character:

```
String source = ...
    
bool starts = source.StartsWith(STX.ToString()); 
bool contains = source.Contains(STX);
```